# How do I using Regedit Change the Color of both Borders and Text Box in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, colors

I have some custom version of Windows 8 and it seems they custom edited the default color of the borders for all windows to be black.

While trying to find the string to edit in Regedit, I also by accident changed the default color of all texts boxes. So in my Task manager or address url bar is a weird fuschia pink color.

So I need to know where to change this one back to white. As well as still being able to change the borders like originally intended.

Please and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The defaults for all color-related settings, found it the registry at **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors**:

```
"Window"="255 255 255"
"GradientInactiveTitle"="215 228 242"
"TitleText"="0 0 0"
"ButtonAlternateFace"="0 0 0"
"HotTrackingColor"="0 102 204"
"InactiveTitleText"="0 0 0"
"ActiveBorder"="180 180 180"
"ActiveTitle"="153 180 209"
"ButtonShadow"="160 160 160"
"InactiveTitle"="191 205 219"
"Menu"="240 240 240"
"ButtonDkShadow"="105 105 105"
"HilightText"="255 255 255"
"ButtonText"="0 0 0"
"GrayText"="109 109 109"
"InfoText"="0 0 0"
"MenuText"="0 0 0"
"MenuHilight"="51 153 255"
"Hilight"="51 153 255"
"Background"="0 0 0"
"AppWorkspace"="171 171 171"
"ButtonLight"="227 227 227"
"GradientActiveTitle"="185 209 234"
"WindowFrame"="100 100 100"
"InfoWindow"="255 255 225"
"MenuBar"="240 240 240"
"Scrollbar"="200 200 200"
"ButtonFace"="240 240 240"
"WindowText"="0 0 0"
"ButtonHilight"="255 255 255"
"InactiveBorder"="244 247 252"
```

Assuming you haven't changed anything else, you can find the one in your registry that differs and set it back to the value in the list.

**note:must reboot after changes**

Comment: No need to reboot, just restart explorer. Or if you have/install *chocolatey*, with the `refreshenv` command. There are other powershell one-liners for that around here as well...